# How do i modify the value of a cookie with the use of a jQuery plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

I've made a oop php script, that adds products to a cart, it'll be saved in a cookie '$_COOKIE['cart']'. If i add a product to the cookie it looks like this

```
$_COOKIE['cart'][0]['id'] = 1;
$_COOKIE['cart'][0]['quantity'] = 156;
```

On the cart page itself, i want to use jQuery, to modify the quantity without refreshing. I have found this: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie , but i'm not really sure, how do i reach for example cart.0.quantity by using that jquery way? I think if i only do $.cookie('cart', 'value');, that it will overwrite the whole cookie.

Comment: How are you serialising the `$_COOKIE` variable? Whats the cookie look like in browser console?

Comment: Remember jQuery is just a framework built on vanilla javascript so use [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

Comment: If it was me I would to do all this using ajax and localStorage(if you need to store locally)

Comment: i serialize the cookie with json_encode if that's what you mean?

Comment: yes, so then get it json.parse it then set it again. i.e the lib does not support `$.cookie('cart[0]', {id:1,quantity:157}, 'json');`

Comment: also it would be `cart[0].quantity` not `cart.0.quantity`

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right. So at first i use javascript it's onchange, to see if a value in the shopping cart has changed. After that i actually need to call the cookie within javascript, somehow with json.parse i need to rewrite only the part where i want to change the quantity. And than recreate the cookie. But i'm not sure how JSON.parse works fully